# underscore array comprehension?

Tags: javascript, node.js, underscore.js

I was using list comprehension in Python and trying to translate to nodejs using underscore library . So in Python I have below (building list of ip addresses;):

```
return ["10." + str(x) + "." + str(y) + ".1" for x in range(192, 256) for y in range(0, 256)]
```

I know underscore can do _.range(192, 256) but is there an easy and short way to do all above in underscore or any js library ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ES7 has [`Array comprehension`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Array_comprehensions) and it can be used with ES6 [`Template string`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings), and `_.range()` to get the result.

```
[for (x of _.range(192, 256)) for (y of _.range(0, 256)) `10.${x}.${y}.1`];
```

As array comprehension is only supported by FF the moment, you'll have to use the [babel](http://babeljs.io/docs/advanced/transformers/other/comprehensions/) transpiler.

Answer (score 0):

I think I know, just do npm search ;)

```
var comprehend = require('array-comprehension');
result = comprehend([10], _.range(192, 256), _.range(0,256), function(x,y,z) {return x + "." + y + "." + z + ".1" });
```